# Convert calls to read and write YAML data to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, yaml

I am editing Java code which stores data in a YAML file, but I need to make it use MySQL instead, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. The code makes request to read and write data such as `SQLset("top.middle.nameleaf", "Joe")` or `SQLget("top.middle.ageleaf")`. These functions are defined by me. This would be simple with YAML, but I'm not sure how to implement this with SQL. Thanks in advance. Another thing is that if `top.middle` was set to null then `top.middle.nameleaf` would be removed, like it would in YAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql doesn't work in the same way as yaml.  you cannot blindly replace a yaml solution with a sql one.  you will have to actually think about what you want to do.

1. get a basic understanding of how sql works, with tables and columns, and relationships between them.
2. define a set of tables that match the data you have in yaml (it might be one table for each structure, and a foreign key linking tables that are nested in yaml).
3. work out how best to adapt your code to use sql.  one approach might be to work with yaml until the data are "ready" and then translate the final yaml structure to sql.  alternatively, you may want to replace all your yaml-routines with sql routines, but without doing the above it is hard to say exactly how that will work.

Comment: I replaced all the YAML gets and sets with sql ones. If I transfered the final yaml structure to sql, how would this work?

Comment: that depends on 1, 2 and 3 above.  i really cannot do your job for you here.  sorry.